# How to make contents of First Column not to overflow to Second Column in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am working with css of two column-sections, section one and section tow. Using css Column, I would like first column of section one occupied the available space of first colum without overflow to second column like this

[image]

The red highlight content should continue inside Section One Column,  because when I print preview document there is much available free space underneath Section One Column that its content should not overflow to Section Two Column at all.

```css
.two-column {
  -webkit-columns: 100px 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-columns: 100px 2;
  /* Firefox */
  columns: 100px 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-gap: 40px;
  /* Firefox */
  column-gap: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="two-column">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- SECTION ONE -->
      <h1>Section One</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- SECTION TOW -->
      <h1>Section Two</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There could be another solution like using flex-box side by side but I need to achieve this using CSS Column Style only. How could I do that? Thanks.

Comment: I see you are using Bootstrap. Are you looking for pure CSS solution or with Bootstrap?

Comment: @kiranvj Because I want to inherit some style from bootstrap for actual column division is to archive by pure css instead. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic code for 2 column using flex. You have class `row` which is a bootstrap class, which might be conflicting with your CSS.

```css
.my-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.my-col {
  flex-basis: 0;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-row">
  <div class="my-col"> Put your col here</div>
  <div class="my-col"> Put your second col here</div>
</div>
```

**2 column with your contents without overflow**

[image]

```css
.my-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.my-col {
  flex-basis: 0;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-row">
  <div class="my-col">
    <!-- SECTION ONE -->
    <h1>Section One</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="my-col">
    <!-- SECTION TOW -->
    <h1>Section Two</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated solution after OP comment without changing html (Just CSS change)**

```css
.two-column {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}

.two-column .row {
  flex-basis: 0 ;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1 ;
  flex-grow: 1 ;
  max-width: 100%;
  display:block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="two-column">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- SECTION ONE -->
      <h1>Section One</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- SECTION TOW -->
      <h1>Section Two</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is works, but could I achieve this by css column instead because It's hard to modify to change my project html structure?

Comment: @HouyNarun Answer updated. Your html is not modified, only CSS is modified.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be badly used in bootstrap. 
Classes in bootstrap: Row is horizontal by default so you can make use of that and define the column width by using bootstrap class: col-md-6 (Half of width).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
      <!-- SECTION ONE -->
      <h1>Section One</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <!-- SECTION TOW -->
      <h1>Section Two</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one simple way to do it with bootstrap using Bootstrap Grid. Description here [Bootstrap Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp) with class `col-lg-6`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">

      <!-- SECTION ONE -->
      <h1>Section One</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
    </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">

      <!-- SECTION ONE -->
      <h1>Section Two</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code (display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>index</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #container {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
    
    .left {
      order: 1;
      width: 50%;
      padding: 30px;
    }
    
    .right {
      order: 1;
      width: 50%;
      padding: 30px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="left">
      <h1>Section One</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam molestias quas iste debitis animi aspernatur, deleniti nam? Vitae iste quia placeat? Ducimus ratione quod impedit ipsam distinctio et odit quidem.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h1>Section Two</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui vel quia, facere numquam vitae atque, neque doloremque cumque eos porro. Dolorum hic iusto quo, numquam eius magnam illum dignissimos id.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can provide CSS style "overflow: hidden" so that any overflow of data is not visible.

Comment: That will not help with this problem at all